# How to get position of every instantiated GameObject Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am newbie, trying to make a simple tap-to-jump type 2D game, I was able to figure out things on my own but I can't do anything with this problem. 
So the problem is:- 
            1). I have three scripts Movement.cs, Obstacle.cs, and Score.cs (both Movement.cs and Score.cs are attached to "Player" gameObject).

2). In Score.cs I want to score++ every time the player jumps and avoid collision with obstacle (just like flappy bird).

3) Here is my Score.cs script:
 I include snippet because of "code not formatted" error

```css
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Score : MonoBehaviour 
{
 public GameObject obstacle;
 public Obstacle obs;
 public int score;

 void Start () 
 {
  obstacle = GameObject.Find("Crate");
  obs = obstacle.GetComponent<Obstacle>();
 }

 void Update () 
 {
  if (obs.transform.position.x <= transform.position.x);
  {
   score++;
   Debug.Log (score);
  }
  Debug.Log (score);
 }
}
```

Above mentioned script is generating following error

MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'Obstacle' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it. Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.

What I discover is that, that "obs.transform.position.x" is giving the position of original prefab and not the position of copy it is generating(I observe it when I use Debug.Log(obs.transform.position.x)).

4). My Obstacle.cs script is:

Again for the same reason I include snippet.

```css
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Obstacle : MonoBehaviour {

 public GameObject crate;
 //public GameObject clone;
 public float t = 1f;
 public int score = 0;
 public float startingPositionX = 2.53f;
 public float startingPositionY = -3.50f;

 void Start () 
 {
  Invoke ("Generate", t);
 } 

 void Update()
 {
  var x = -6f;
  var y = 0f;
  rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2 (x, y);
  //Debug.Log(clone.transform.position.x);

  /*if(clone.transform.position.x == -9.53f)
  {
   score++;
   Debug.Log(score);
  }*/

  Destroy (crate, 3.0f);
 }

 void Generate()
 {
  /*clone = */Instantiate (crate, new Vector3 (startingPositionX, startingPositionY, 0f), Quaternion.identity); 
 }
}
```

I tried assigning "clone" the copy of my crate prefab and doing the score thing in my Obstacle.cs script but it also didn't worked.

5). Now I am unable to increase score by 1 because of the above mentioned errors and problems, funny part is that my score is increasing like number of frames per second.

Phew! that's all I hope you guys can understand my problem and provide me solution. Question is very little but I thought I should explain it and make it as clear as I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why didn't this work? I tried assigning "clone" the copy of my crate prefab and doing the score thing in my Obstacle.cs script but it also didn't worked. Did you cast it to a GameObject? like

```
clone = Instantiate (crate, new Vector3 (startingPositionX, startingPositionY, 0f), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
```

? 
What you have now is giving you a nullreference because you are trying to access the transfrom property of a destroyed object.

Comment: yes I did this too but it didn't work, by the way I was confused about what should I assign to the gameObjects(crate, and clone) so I assign my crate prefab to both of them. I don't if this is the problem.

Comment: in Obstacle  don't destriy the crate  - the prefab you are later instantiating, but destroy the clone. In the Score  class you've referenced the main object instead of it's instance. In the Generate class add GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponenet<Score>().obstacle = clone. And in the score class before veryfing the position verify if your object is null or not. Ex. if(obs!=null &&obs.transfrom !=null) // than your code

Comment: Be carefull this is an ad hoc solution to verify if it works. If it does than use GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponenet<Score>() only in the Start and save a reference to it. GameObject.Find() is kindof slow and might impact performance later on

Comment: Okay so what I got from your reply is: 1) Destroy the clone. 2). Verify the object if it is null or not. 3). I am confused (I assumed when you said "Generate class" you meant Obstacle.cs) what exactly following code will do  "GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponenet<Score>()". I am really new to this unity (this is my second day of using unity.)

Comment: And one more thing how can I refer instance instead of the main object in inspector?

Comment: You cannot refer runtime instance from Editor. 1. yes 2 yes. GameObject.Fin(name) finds a gameObject from the scene with the name name. I meant generate **function** not class.

Comment: You can reference a prefab, but not a runtime created object from Editor.

Comment: Okay I got this, this was really helpful for me I can't add "Thanks" here but this was really helpful